In C++20, are non-reference tuple elements guaranteed to be nested within the tuple?
Consider the following function, which returns the offset in bytes between the I-th element of a tuple and the tuple address:
template <std::size_t I, class... Ts>
  requires ( ( not std::is_reference_v<Ts> ) && ... )
std::intptr_t tuple_elem_offset(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple)
{
  const auto element_address = reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(&std::get<I>(tuple));
  const auto tuple_address = reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(&tuple);

  return element_address - tuple_address;
}

Is it guaranteed that the value returned is always in the range [0, sizeof(std::tuple<Ts...>))?
I understand tuples are typically implemented using multiple inheritance, and that this would imply the nested-within property for all non-reference objects held by the tuple. My question is: is it enforced by the language?

No, and what are you doing with that information?

it's conditionally-supported if you use offsetof instead of trying to invent it

@Swift-FridayPie I don't think it will work on a tuple.

I would add a assert and not try to language-lawyer this. Also I'd switch to char * instead of intptr_t as an intermediate type. Also I vaguely remember something about MSVC placing empty classes at sizeof(T) offset (so technically out of bounds), but I'm not sure if this affects tuples (or even if I remember correctly).

@HolyBlackCat yeha, because we have no named member in this case. Also, some old MSVC  implementations had standard layout. But they did that in quite round-about way - by defining template for each number of argument (limited number of arguments supported).

There is no guarantee that the elements are nested in the tuple object, although I have never seen an implementation that doesn't behave that way.
Regardless of the answer to your title question however, the behavior of the shown program is implementation-defined.
There is no guarantee given in the standard that reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t> on a pointer will return a value related to the address that the pointer represents or that it can be used to calculate offsets between objects and their subobjects. But again, in practice that is the only behavior I have seen in implementations.
Being able to calculate offsets like this does not imply that it can be used to get access to the tuple elements though from some other original pointer. So it isn't clear how knowing these offsets would be helpful.

Also, it isn't even guaranteed that the memory occupied by an object such as std::tuple<Ts...> is contiguous, which you seem to imply otherwise with [0, sizeof(std::tuple<Ts...>)). That is only guaranteed for standard-layout types and trivially-copyable types. (Although this in practice only matters for virtual inheritance that should in turn be irrelevant for a normal std::tuple implementation.)

PS. if tuple implemented  via inheritance, such structure doesn't have standard memory layout (all data members must be declared in single base class or in most derived class). and therefore any attempt to use offsetof macro equivalent (what OP tried to brut-force) is conditionally-supported, i.e. depends on implementation.


Is it guaranteed that the value returned is always in the range [0, sizeof(std::tuple<Ts...>))?

Counter example with evil class:
struct Evil
{
    void* operator&() const { static int dummy; return &dummy; }
};

then
tuple_elem_offset<Is>(std::tuple{Evil{}}) would be outside of the range
Demo

Now that's a scary thought - a singleton tuple

OP should have used std::addressof instead of &, that is true. But I feel this is outside the scope of the question. This answer could be a great comment though. Demo
